Is it possible to Retrieve the code from SSJS Script activity from Automation using API?
I am planning to display the Activities from Automation Build, I already found the SOAP object for query activities, but I cannot find an soap object or a rest endpoint for this SSJS retrieving code.

It's not a SOAP object, but a REST route:
https://{{et_subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/automation/v1/scripts


Thank you Adam, that works on my end
